# How can I find answers or question from the last 7 days?

Tags: support, search

I contributed to the Tor Weekly Newsletter in the last weeks. So I looked for some questions and answers in the last seven days and picked some of them. I figured that seeing all answers or questions from the last seven days would ease this task. Is there some search mechanism which could help me here?

Comment: I don't think there is (hopefully someone will prove me wrong); thanks for getting this in the tor weekly newsletter though, and good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stack Exchange search does have some [advanced tips](https://tor.stackexchange.com/search) (click the "Advanced Search Tips" link to see all of the options).

If I wanted to see just questions, I'd start by filtering out answers from the results, as well as closed questions:

```
closed:no is:question
```

Then I could filter further by finding questions with [at least one answer, with an accepted answer, and a score of at least two](https://tor.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a1%20hasaccepted%3ayes%20closed%3ano%20score%3a2%20is%3aquestion).

```
answers:1 hasaccepted:yes closed:no score:2 is:question
```

To see the last seven days, click "newest" at the top of the search results so they're ordered from newest to oldest. Hope this helps.